# execution-time is infinite on simple select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, infinite, execution-time

relatively new to this.

I have a stored procedure that should run when a job is triggered. It all worked fine with the files containing test data that I used for import and testing (excel sheets). I got a new file to test with my solution before deploying, but after having executed the job given the new file the stored procedure just keeps loading without having anything done.

I tried to delete the (excel)file and start again, but it says it's open in another program (it isn't). I then noticed that anytime I try to perform a simple select on one of the tables that are used in the stored procedure, it just keeps loading and never finishes. None of the simple commands work.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM Cleaned_Rebate
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Cleaned_Rebate
TRUNCATE TABLE Cleaned_Rebate
DELETE FROM Cleaned_Rebate
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cleaned_Rebate
```

I also tried to create a new stored procedure identical to the original one, but it just never executes the create query. it keeps on loading. It only creates the new one if I remove 90% of the code.

I can't even execute the stored procedure for the sake of saving it (f5) with just an added comment...

I don't know what is wrong, why, or what I should do to fix this. Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong? any advice is appreciated!

*I want to add that these aren't any big tables - some of them should be empty even. the data sets aren't large either (about 100-300 rows?)*

Comment: check to see if there are any locks on your table

Comment: there seems to be locks on my table... will investigate further and see how i can release them! Thank you very much!